# Android Preferences - ListPreference from database not working

Tags: android, android-preferences

I am working on adding preferences into my app and everything was going fine until I tried to get an arrays from the database to load into a ListPreference. I am using two two seperate arrays, on for the entries and on for the entryValues. Everything is fine until I try to pass the CharSequence[] to setEntries and set entryValues functions.

Here is the code:

```
public class EditPreferences extends PreferenceActivity {
private SQLiteDatabase db;
private TimesheetDatabaseHelper dbHelp = new TimesheetDatabaseHelper(this);

@SuppressWarnings("deprecation")
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    addPreferencesFromResource(R.xml.preference_activity);

    ListPreference projectsList = (ListPreference)findPreference("@string/perfProjectKey");
    /** Open the database table for reading and writing */
    db = dbHelp.getReadableDatabase();
    String getProjects = "select _id, name from projects;";

    Cursor cu = db.rawQuery(getProjects, null);
    Log.d("Database call:", "Success");
    Log.d("Database Rows Returned:", String.valueOf(cu.getCount()));

    List<String> entries = new ArrayList<String>();
    List<String> entryValues = new ArrayList<String>();

    if(cu != null && cu.getCount() > 0){
        cu.moveToFirst();

        do {
            entries.add(cu.getString(1));
            entryValues.add(Integer.toString(cu.getInt(0)));
        } while (cu.moveToNext());

    }
    cu.close();
    db.close();
    Log.d("Out of the loop", "and probably closed");

    final CharSequence[] entryCharSeq = entries.toArray(new CharSequence[entries.size()]);
    final CharSequence[] entryValsChar = entryValues.toArray(new CharSequence[entryValues.size()]);
    Log.d("Past the cast", "maybe we work?");
    Log.d("Entries size:", Integer.toString(entries.size()));
    Log.d("Entry Values size:", Integer.toString(entryValues.size()));

    projectsList.setEntries(entryCharSeq);
    Log.d("We got here:", "TRUE!");
    projectsList.setEntryValues(entryValsChar);

}
```

}

According to the stacktrace, which I can post if necessary, it's a nullPointerException on line 55, and 55 is

```
projectsList.setEntries(entryCharSeq);
```

I don't know whats wrong. Hopefully someone can help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Change

```
ListPreference projectsList = (ListPreference)findPreference("@string/perfProjectKey");
```

To

```
ListPreference projectsList = (ListPreference)findPreference(getString(R.string.perfProjectKey));
```

Comment: Thank you so much. I've been stuck on this for far too long. Now, can you tell me why it worked? It doesn't seem like that big a deal to me.

Comment: In your original code you try to find a preference literally name @string/perfProjectKey but you really want the name to be the name that is store in the string.xml name perfProjectKey which is what getString does.

Comment: Ah, ok, that makes sense. I wasn't thinking about the string like that. Thanks so much!

Comment: @David Manpearl Thank you, you are getting there.